# Java database query not printing out in console

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I'm creating my first Java program that pulls data from a **MySql database**. I'm having trouble getting the result from a query to print in console. My program compiles without error but **out.print command not displaying content in console**. I'm using Intellij IDEA 15.0.2.

```
import java.sql.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/animal";
    String user = "username";
    String pwd = "password";
    try {
        Connection connection =
             DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd); // Get Connection
     Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); // Create Statement
        String query = "SELECT * FROM animal";
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query); // Execute Query
        while (resultSet.next()) { // Process Results
            out.print(resultSet.getInt("animal_id"));

        }
    } catch (SQLException se) { }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print out to console the correct command is

```
System.out.print("Whatever you want to print");
```

not

```
out.print("Whatever you want to print");
```

Comment: So this is the issue ??

Comment: I just happened to notice that, if his other code is correct, then yes.

Comment: I guess he has used either static imports or something, otherwise code would not compile.

Comment: @BradStell If it is your guess then it should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I will do that in the future @YoungHobbit, my mistake. But had his code been correct then not having **System**.out.print(); will not print anyways.

Comment: @YoungHobbit you are correct I did import static java.lang.System.*; sorry I should have mentioned that above. The program does compile without error.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.. as BradStell said you have to use

```
      System.out.print(resultSet.getInt("animal_id"));
```

instead of

```
      out.print(resultSet.getInt("animal_id"));
```

Another suggestion that I would like to make is Always do something on catching an exception. You have no code in the catch block. Atleast try to print the exception there. That would help you very much in finding errors in your code .

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't think that is the problem. I've change my code to reflect your suggestion. However I still get the a successful compile but no data printed from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the database driver. I needed to use the **forName method()**, and add the driver url for MySql. After I successfully implemented this class I was able to create sql queries without issue. Thanks for the tip with the exception handling @Senthil Vidhiyakar

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.print("Working");
    }
    catch (Exception e){ System.out.println("Not working");}
```

I also had to connect the mysql connector jar. The process for doing this in Intellij IDEA is as follows.

**File >> Project Structure** "The project structure window will appear then on the **left side menu *click Modules*** in the main content area **click on the Dependencies tab**. Next **click the green +**. *Choose option 1 JARs or directories*. Finally, navigate to the mysql connector jar. Then **click apply, and ok**."